# Amplifying current using a buffer

Tags: current, amplifier, buffer, distortion

The amplification of this amplifier is 1. So we have a buffer. But the question i wanted to ask was.

- What can we tell about the current amplification of the circuit below? Is this circuit useful?
- I also found out that when i apply 8Vp-p at the input, i have a distortion at the output. Why does it happen around that voltage? or a basic explanation on it!

[image]

Comment: Rb and Re are missing. The distortion (should be clipping imo) that you described in your second question depends on Re because it sets DC offset.

Comment: Isn't a B-GND resistor missing too? The aim is to have symmetrical headerom, so Ve must be ~ Vcc/2. With only Rb this depends critically on the B of Q1.

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen Theoretically you could make the values of Rb and Re such that it would bias the base at VCC/2 (or a different value). But since Ib depends on the beta and beta varies a lot you'd have to use a different Rb value for each transistor. So it's not a good and practical solution to only have an Rb to VCC. Indeed for a practical design an Rb to GND is also needed.

Answer (score 1):

The current amplification (A<sub>i</sub>) is defined as *the output current divided by the input current*. So to calulate A<sub>i</sub> you need to find expressions for i<sub>i</sub> and i<sub>o</sub>, and divide.

First assume C<sub>in</sub> and C<sub>out</sub> are a short at the signal frequency. This is an approximation for AC signals; Now there are only resistors left. The suppply is a kind of capacitor too, so its also considered a short.

The input current is split into a current lost in the bias setup (Rb in this case), and the current into the base. The impedance of the base is given by h<sub>ie</sub>. Knowing this you can calculate how much of the input current makes it into the base:

$$i_b = {{i_i R_b} \over {h_{ie}+R_b}}$$

Rewriting this gives the input current:

$$i_i = {{R_b i_b + h_{ie} ib} \over {R_b}}$$

The transistor amplifies the base current by a factor h<sub>fe</sub> to give the collector current; Together with the base current itself this gives the emitter current:
$$i_e = {(1+h_{fe}) ib} $$

The emitter current is split between R<sub>e</sub> and the output chain (R<sub>1</sub>+R<sub>L</sub>). So you calculate the current through the load:

$$i_o = {{R_e i_e} \over {R_1+R_L+R_E}}$$

Now, once you have expressions for both i<sub>i</sub> and i<sub>o</sub>, you divide them, and see what's left.

$$ A_i = {i_o \over i_i} = {{R_e {(1+h_{fe}) ib}} \over {R_1+R_L+R_E}} \cdot 
{{R_b} \over {R_b i_b + h_{ie} ib}}
 = {{(R_L+R_1)(h_{fe}+1)R_b} \over {(R_L+R_E+R_1)(h_{ie}+R_b)}}$$

At this point i<sub>b</sub> and i<sub>e</sub> disappear from the equation. All that's left are numbers to fill in.

For example take: h<sub>fe</sub>=100, h<sub>ie</sub>=1000 ohm, R<sub>b</sub>=100 kohm and R<sub>e</sub>=200 ohm. Using these values gives a current amplification of **8**.

So the circuit may be useful (provided the values chosen result in a valid DC operating point, and the supply can accomodate the voltage range implied).

Comment: so to make myself clear, our any current input will be amplified by times 8. right? [io = 8 * i in] So we have a good current amplification. And how much can we expect normally the input current to be? @peter